# Übersetzung von "I did my master's degree at Oxford"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I did my master's degree at Oxford.

Wie sagt man das auf Deutsch? Funktionieren alle Folgenden, und gibt es andere typische Weisen es auszudrücken?

> (a) Ich habe meinen Master in Oxford gemacht.
>
> (b) Ich habe meinen Masterabschluss in Oxford gemacht.
>
> (c) Ich habe meinen Mastergrad in Oxford gemacht.

Comment: _(Akademischer) Grad_ ist sehr gehoben/fachsprachlich. Es paßt damit schlecht zu einem simplen _machen_. Wenn schon, dann _erwerben_.

Comment: @chirlu: Oder besser noch "erlangen" oder (passiver) "erhalten". Bei "erwerben" schwingt immer die Mehrdeutigkeit mit, dass man den Grad möglicherweise nicht auf dem regulären (seriösen) Weg bekommen hat, sondern ihn sich gekauft hat.

Comment: Satz a) und b) sind in Ordnung (aber vom Stil her umgangssprachlicher), ansonsten gilt, was Guidot geantwortet hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich teile die geäußerte Abneigung gegen Zusammenkleben deutscher und englischer Wortteile. Dann bleiben Formulierungen wie:

> Ich habe mein [ergänze Fachrichtung]-Studium in Oxford mit dem Master abgeschlossen.

Diesen oder einen ähnlichen Satz wird man in Bewerbungen finden; etwas informeller ist:

> Ich habe einen Master in [Fachrichtung] der Oxford University.

Answer (score 0):

> (a) Ich habe meinen Master in Oxford gemacht.

→ OK

> (b) Ich habe meinen Masterabschluss in Oxford gemacht.

→ mixing German and English – not SO brilliant – doppelt gemoppelt, da Master und Abschluss dieselbe Bedeutung tragen

> (c) Ich habe meinen Mastergrad in Oxford gemacht.

→ mixing German and English – not SO brilliant – never heard it this way

---

Das Problem ist eher, dass man mit dem Begriff Master hier zu Lande wahrscheinlich wenig anfangen kann.

Wir sind viel formeller:

*Ich habe meinen Abschluss/Universitätsabschluss …*

---

Außerdem → *Funktionieren alle folgenden Varianten …* oder → *Funktioniert das Folgende …*

Comment: Seit Bologna gibt es in D. statt dem Diplom die Abschlüsse Bachelor und Master. Und das sind immerhin auch schon gut zehn Jahre, dass diese Absolventen auf dem deutschen Arbeitsmarkt unterwegs sind.

Comment: @Stephie: Erklär das mal deinem 50jährigen Chef ;-) - Und wenn er dich fragen sollte sag ihm Du seist 'Junggeselle/Jungfrau' und ein Meister darin... ;-)

Comment: Brauchen wir das wirklich alles um 'competitive' zu bleiben? Oder gibt es nur mehr Anglo-Saxon bosses in Germany...?

Comment: Wenn mein Chef das noch nicht mitbekommen hat, dann bin ich in der falschen Firma... Und eine Diskussion, ob die Reform sinnvoll ist oder nicht macht an dieser Stelle keinen Sinn, für weitere Erklärungen wäre dann die Kommission der Europäischen Bildungsminister zuständig. Aber am Fakt, dass seit Jahren auch aus deutschen Hochschulen eben Bachelor und Master ausgebildet werden, kommen wir nicht vorbei. Egal, was unser Sprachgefühl sagt.

Comment: You must be some youngster ;-)

Comment: Danke für das Kompliment, aber: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna-Prozess

Comment: "da Master und Abschluss die selbe Bedeutung tragen" - das sehe ich aber nicht so. Der Master ist *ein* möglicher Abschluss von einer Universität. Genau genommen stimmt sogar nicht einmal das, sondern der Abschluss ist der Statuswechsel bzw. das Ereignis, eine Universitätsausbildung erfolgreich zu beenden, während "Master" ein akademischer Grad. Somit würde "Master-Abschluss" völlig korrekt eine zusätzliche Information liefern, die im "Abschluss" alleine nicht enthalten wäre.